# How to use Php Comparison and Ternary Operators in this code?

Tags: php, concatenation, ternary-operator

I've been reading the [documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and trying to make a piece of code work to no avail. I'm wanting to check a radio input if the value matches the one in the database. I'm posting the relevant piece of code.

Original if statement

```
if(isset($_POST['radioValue'])){
if($prospectAnswer == $script[$getScriptAA]){
echo 'checked="checked';}}
```

What I have tried so far...

```
$input .=  ' <input  
'.((isset($_POST['radioValue']) 
&& ($prospectAnswer == $script[$getScriptAA])) ? 'checked="checked').'
              type="radio" 
              name="sAnswer" 
              value="'.$script[$getScriptAA].'">
<span class="radiotext"> '.$script[$getScriptAA].'</span>';
```

Comment: You're missing ":". As in, `(condition) ? checked : unchecked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code is missing the 2nd part of the ternary, add `: ''` after `'checked="checked"'`.

```
$input .=  ' <input  
'.(isset($_POST['radioValue']) && $prospectAnswer == $script[$getScriptAA] ? 'checked="checked"' : '').'
              type="radio" 
              name="sAnswer" 
              value="'.$script[$getScriptAA].'">
<span class="radiotext"> '.$script[$getScriptAA].'</span>';
```